# Add write permission to Custom folder files created with windows installer

Tags: windows-installer

I am creating a folder inside programdata folder using windows installer. Running the project i am getting an error while trying to write to the file

```
C:\ProgramData\MyAppFolder\settings_file.sqlite
```

This is the error message

```
attempt to write a read-only database.
```

How can i grant the write permission to the db file and some other files while building the msi file using windows installer

I can see the folder permissions as like this  [image]

any way to make this read and write enables while building this via windows installer

Answer (score 0):

***ACL Permissioning***: Adding write permissions for regular users is usually considered an anti-pattern, but sometimes you need to share a file among all users of the PC for pragmatic purposes.

***Write Access***: For the record: [Here is a list of approaches to deal with permission denied issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587622/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-running-exe-under-program-files/50588465#50588465). Most of the options listed are not good at all - and that is why the list was made - we need to remember why they are bad and what alternatives exist.

***Deployment Tool***: Application of custom ACL permissioning - to open a file in a protected disk location for writing by all users - is different depending on what tool you use to make your MSI. Since you don't specify WiX, Installshield, Advanced Installer or something else I am not sure how to answer. Let me use links instead:

***WiX***:

- [Different WiX permission elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324552/is-wix-changing-the-permissions-on-my-notes-ini-file/49325684#49325684) - there are two different PermissionEx elements (!)

  - [**PermissionEx**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/permissionex.html) (**Util Extension** - WiX's own stuff)

    - ***Util Version***: [Wix: How to set permissions for folder and all sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272406/wix-how-to-set-permissions-for-folder-and-all-sub-folders)
  - [**PermissionEx**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/permissionex.html) (**MSI5** only - uses the built in **`MsiLockPermissionsEx`** Table)

    - ***MSI5 Version***: [How to deny folder permission to Users with wix installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543312/how-to-deny-folder-permission-to-users-with-wix-installer/49546999#49546999)
- There are two more (do not use):

  - [Permission](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/permission.html) (legacy MSI LockPermission table)
  - [FileSharePermission](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/filesharepermission.html) (for share permissioning - use when you need share permissioning)

***Installshield***:

- [Configuring Permissions for Files and Folders](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/ConfiguringPrmssnsFile.htm?)
- [Setting Permissions in Windows Installer: MSILockPermissionsEX and ISLockPermissions](https://blogs.flexera.com/installtalk/2010/11/setting-permissions-in-windows-installer-msilockpermissionsex-and-islockpermissions/)
- [Installshield Folder Permissions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460201/installshield-folder-permissions-not-working)

***Advanced Installer***:

- Apply permissions by right clicking a folder and going to properties: [**Permission Dialog**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/permission-dialog.html).
- It seems this uses the old, legacy **`LockPermission table`**.

---

There are some other tools as described here: [Short List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). [Secondary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/129130) (more links).

---

***Other Links***:

- [Different Ways of Giving Permissions in Your Windows Installer](https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/different-ways-giving-permissions-your-windows-installer)
- [Per Machine App Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980113/per-machine-app-registration/46984981#46984981)
- [Create a .config folder in the user folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695746/create-a-config-folder-in-the-user-folder)
- [Desktop applicaton not opening after installation in client system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512998/desktop-applicaton-not-opening-after-installation-in-client-system/53530377#53530377)
- http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/permissionex.html