# Setting File Sharing Permissions With Visual Studio Setup And Deployment Project

Tags: windows-installer, file-permissions, file-sharing

I'm looking for a way to programatically set the file permissions for read/write for "everyone" as well as have files shared out to everyone upon install. Does anyone have any information on how to achieve this?

We have 3 directories we create in programfiles for our product that we'd like to have, upon install, shared to "everyone". I see answers to set the permissions but we also want the directories to be shared.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: [Maybe check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145282/how-to-include-inherited-permissions-when-specifying-permissions-for-a-file-inst#comment97038474_55145282). And a [direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55124447/129130). Remember that opening up rights is undesirable. [Some options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50588465/129130).

Comment: We understand, but there is a central function of our software in which the users will have to share these directories anyway so we'd prefer to do it upon install. Thanks for the link I'll look into it

Comment: Hope it solves the problem.