# How to set wix permissionex element on windows hostFile

Tags: wix, wix3

I am trying to set custom iis AppPool user ACL permission on windows hostFile using permisssionEx element in Wix Installer.

However if I try manually by going to properties tab of host file, and click on Add users and add IIS AppPool[My_AppPool], am I'm able to add after a windows pop-up.

Any suggestions using permissionEx element.

I have tried using permissionEx element and also by creating a CustomAction method. But,it didn't work. Below is the code snippet.

[PermissionExCodeImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GSNm.png)

My installer properly installs, but unable to set permission on a host File. Any suggestions on host File.

Comment: I would think opening write access to the ``hosts`` file would be prohibited by the security guys in your company? Might be worth checking first? Could there be mechanisms to revert the ACLs to default for such a core file? I don't know. [PermissionEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55163592/129130). And [some more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55124447/129130).